# Best process to retrieve files daily from outside Azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I've asked this question in the Azure Logic Apps (LA) forum since I've used LA to implement this process but I may also get some valuable input here.

**High-level description**: in one specific client, we need to download, daily, dozens of file from a SFTP location to our servers in order to process their data. This workflow was built, in the past, using tools from a different technology than Azure but what we aimed to have was a general process that could be used for different source systems, different files, etc. With that in mind, our process retrieves, in the beginning, from a database, different variables to be applied to each execution of the process such as:

- Business date
- Remote location path - sftp location
- Local location path - internal server location
- File extension - .csv, .zip, etc
- Number of iterations
- Wait time between iterations
- Dated files - whether files have business date on their name or not

Once all this is defined in the beginning of the process (there's some extra logic to it, not as straight forward as just getting variables but let's assume this for example purposes), the following logic is applied (the image below may help understand the LA flow):

- Search for file in SFTP location
- If file is there, get file size, wait X amount of time and check size again.
- If file isn't there, try again until reaching maximum number of iterations or file is found
- If file's size match, proceed to download the file
- If file's size don't match, try again until reaching maximum number of iterations or file is found

[LA Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRaSs.png)

In our LA, this process is implemented and working fine, we have 2 parameters in LA which is the filename and source system and based on these parameters, all variables are retrieved in the beginning of the process. Those 2 parameters can be changed from LA to LA and by scripting we can automatically deploy multiple LAs (one for each file we need to download). The process uses a schedule trigger since we want to run it at a specific time each day, we don't want to use the trigger of when a file is placed in a remote location since several files may be placed in the remote location which we aren't interested in.

One limitation that I can see compared to our current process is having multiple LAs grouped under one type of pipeline, where we can group multiple executions and check the state of them all without needing to check multiple LAs. I'm aware that we can do monitoring of LAs with OMS and, potentially, call multiple LAs from a Data Factory pipeline but I'm not exactly sure how that would work in this case.

Anyway, here is where my **QUESTION** comes in: what would be the best feature in Azure to implement this type of process? LAs works since I have it built, I'm going to take a look at replicate the same process in Data Factory but I'm afraid it may be a bit more complicated to set up this kind of logic there. What else could potentially be used? Really open to all kind of suggestions, just want to make sure I consider all valid options which is hard considering how many different features are offered by Azure and it's hard to keep track of them all.

Appreciate any input, cheers

Comment: I think this bleongs in another stack exchange as it's not a code problem per se. Personally it depends on your client and what they are willing to pay. If you have _strong_ power shell/bash scripting skills then FTP/SFTP > Blob Storage > Data Factory > Data Lake > Databricks ETL > Azure SQL Datawarehouse I'm voting to close this. You need scripts to power on/off the azure services otherwise you'll be paying an arm and a leg.

Comment: It depends on file size / urgency to process them too. You can evaluate Azure Functions too.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio: file size can vary from less than 1M to a few hundred MB and, ocasionally, >1GB. The urgency is that these files need to be pulled and processed every night.

Comment: @Datanovice : I understand it may not be the most correct location for this kind of question but appreciate your input anyway. Where would you run those scripts to pull data from SFTP to Blob Storage? Some kind of VM running with jobs scheduled?

Comment: Yes exactly either Python or bash/power shell scripts on a remote vm that has access to clients servers.